# what should be "ideal" floor coloring in a bright area?

Tags: flooring

I am planning to go for white tiles . I live in a place where there is a lot of light (near the equator) . Will white be good or should I go for little darker colors (since white reflects a lot of light) ?

edit : This is not a question to choose color, but to understand light vs dark .

Comment: Welcome to the site, Vinoth.  Unfortunately, questions about choosing colors are considered to be off-topic here; see this question on meta.diy for more information: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/244/22

Comment: Ya . Ok :) . I know it is a very subjective question . But I was trying to understand how light affects colors.

Comment: @Niall : I'm actually for it ... although choosing what shade best matches someone's personality should be discouraged, light vs. dark has affects on heating & cooling, issues with cleaning / showing dirt, etc.  My only issue is it might be borderline the word 'ideal' ... if it was a question on advantages/disadvantages of white vs. darker tiles, particularly for areas near the equator, I'd have no issues at all.

Comment: @Joe - I Agree.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange.  Glad to have you.  Be aware as Niall said, subjective questions should be on the meta section.  Color is such a personal item and not knowing your particular circumstances make it impossible to give you a good definitive answer.  Good Luck

Comment: Being married to one, I'm biased, but I strongly suggest hiring an interior designer to help you with this sort of question. They will be able to give advice based on the actual space, their knowledge of color theory, and what they can learn about your lifestyle and preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Like you say, brighter tiles make the room brighter (and apparently "larger"). Darker make it... darker and smaller. The "brightness" also depends on window size and orientation (relative to what direction the sun shines from) and room size.

You need to balance whatever is your taste with all these factors. The rest is subjective. Some people like darker rooms even if they're small, others prefer to make them as bright and apparently large as possible at all times.